# Custom dialog modal not working without method: delete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog

I have a custom dialog that looks like this:

```
$(function() {
    $.rails.allowAction = function(link) {
        if (!link.attr('data-confirm')) {
            return true;
        }
        $.rails.showConfirmDialog(link);
        return false;
    };
    $.rails.confirmed = function(link) {
        link.removeAttr('data-confirm');
        return link.trigger('click.rails');
    };
    return $.rails.showConfirmDialog = function(link) {
        var html, message;
        message = link.attr('data-confirm');
        html = "<div class=\"modal\" id=\"confirmationDialog\">\n  <div class=\"modal-dialog\">\n    <div class=\"modal-content\">\n      <div class=\"modal-header\">\n        <a class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"modal\">×</a>\n        <h4>" + message + "</h4>\n      </div>\n      <div class=\"modal-footer\">\n        <a data-dismiss=\"modal\" class=\"btn btn-info\">" + "Cancel" + "</a>\n        <a data-dismiss=\"modal\" class=\"btn btn-primary confirm\">" + "Confirm" + "</a>\n      </div>\n    </div>\n  </div>\n</div>";
        $(html).modal();
        return $('#confirmationDialog .confirm').on('click', function() {
            return $.rails.confirmed(link);
        });
    };
});
```

The custom dialog is working when I use method: delete, but I have also a delete button that doesn't use the method:

```
  <%= link_to delete_file_path(current_user), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm " do %>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
  <% end %>
```

With that link button it appears the custom dialog but when I click confirm nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

A controller action is routed by both a URL and HTTP method sent by the client. Since you're trying to hit the `destroy` action you need to send a `delete` action along with your request, otherwise `link_to` sends a `GET` which will likely either cause a 404, or different action than you might expect. This is why the link behaves differently when `method: :delete` is prevent vs. not.

Comment: but this delete link is working well without the custom dialog, if I put method delete it says `No route matches [DELETE] "/delete_file.1"`

Comment: Then your helper method doesn't match your routes definition. Can you post your `routes.rb` here?

Comment: `get 'delete_file' => "analyse#delete_file"` . this is without method: :delete